# Is it ok for a H.264 stream to say its SAR and DAR are [0:1]

Tags: video-streaming, h.264

I've implemented a video viewing application to show video streams from cameras. It uses the FFMPEG library to receive a (H.264) multicast video stream and decode it to images, which are shown by my application. It's working pretty well, but now there is a specific camera stream that causes my application to crash.
When probing the stream with ffprobe, it shows that according to the stream info, both SAR and DAR are [0:1]. I have never seen this before with other cameras. It's the SAR that's causing the problems in my application, so for now I've patched it to assume a SAR of [1:1] in case the stream indicates an invalid SAR.

My question is rather generic, and not so much specifically about my application:

*Is it allowed for a camera to report a SAR (and/or DAR) of [0:1], which seems to make no sense? And if this allowed, is there some default SAR and/or DAR that should be assumed in this situation?*

Below a part of the ffprobe output, in case this is relevant...

```
$ ffprobe -v info -show_streams -protocol_whitelist udp,rtp,file stream_system_1_cam_11_live.sdp
ffprobe version 3.2.14-1~deb9u1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
Input #0, sdp, from 'stream_system_1_cam_11_live.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : /videoinput_1:0/h264_1/media.stm
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.333700, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1920x1080, 30 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=0:1
display_aspect_ratio=0:1
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=42
color_range=pc
color_space=bt470bg
color_transfer=smpte170m
color_primaries=bt470bg
chroma_location=left
field_order=progressive
[/STREAM]
```

It's the **sample_aspect_ratio=0:1** and **display_aspect_ratio=0:1** that surprised me!
Any ideas, info and opinions are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From H.264 specs chapter "E.2.1 VUI parameters semantics":

> sar_width and sar_height shall be relatively prime or equal to 0. When
> aspect_ratio_idc is equal to 0 or sar_width is equal to 0 or
> sar_height is equal to 0, the sample aspect ratio shall be considered
> unspecified by this Recommendation | International Standard.

So it means that SAR is unspecified.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right spec for this. But... if the stream doesn't provide a SAR nor DAR, how should a displaying application determine to how show the video images? Is the only option to just 'assume' a SAR?
And should this stream be considered 'faulty' for not providing all needed data to show it? (I.e. can I contact the camera vendor and blame them for not following the specs?)

Comment: Stream is correct according to H.264 specs. Such information (like SAR, color matrix, color primaries and almost all of the VUI) is optional and so unspecified is valid value. As for what to do: 1) try to find such information at another abstraction layer i.e. in container (mkv / mp4) 2) assume some value as default, for SAR it most probably would be 1:1 (square).

Comment: Thanks again... As there is no container available (as it's a h264 live stream from a camera over rtp), the best I can do in my application is assuming a [1:1] SAR...(In this particular situation it is indeed [1:1]) I guess ffplay and vlc are doing the same thing...
Many thanks for thinking along!